# I can’t configure virtual hosts in Apache, although I do everything according to the instructions. What is the reason?

Tags: apache, ubuntu-18.04

I can’t configure virtual hosts in Apache, although I do everything according to the [instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/apache-ubuntu-18-04-ru). What is the reason?
I'm trying to configure virtual hosts in Apache, and it fails. I carry out the instruction without problems, but this does not work for me.

**Ubunttu 18.04**. The root directory is **/var/www/html**

There is an index.html and it is accessible from the network.
Now, if you just type the address of the site in the browser, then it still displays, **/var/www/html/index.php**, and not the **index.html** from the virtual host. That is, it turns out that virtual hosts do not work at all.

I did the following:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/xxxxxx.xx/html
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/xxxxxx.xx/html
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/xxxxxx.xx

nano /var/www/xxxxxx.xx/html/index.html
```

Added page code here.

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/xxxxxx.xx.conf
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/xxxxxx.xx.conf
```

I inserted into xxxxxx.xx.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin host1@gmail.com
  ServerName xxxxxx.xx
  ServerAlias www.xxxxxx.xx
  DocumentRoot /var/www/xxxxxx.xx/html
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  DirectoryIndex index.php
</VirtualHost>

sudo a2ensite xxxxxx.xx.conf
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

The directory permissions:

```
user1@host1:/var/www$ ls -l
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov 14 11:05 xxxxxx.xx
drwxr-xr-x 13 www-data www-data 4096 Nov 13 16:14 html
drwxr-xr-x 4 user1 user1 4096 Nov 12 11:03 html-bk

user1@host1:/var/www/xxxxxx.xx$ ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 user1 user1 4096 Nov 14 11:08 html

user1@host1:/var/www/xxxxxx.xx/html$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1 177 Nov 14 11:08 index.html
```

What's wrong? I’m setting up Apache for the first time, yet according to the instructions, there were no errors during execution.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the following change, add index.html instead of index.php

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerAdmin host1@gmail.com
      ServerName xxxxxx.xx
      ServerAlias www.xxxxxx.xx
      DocumentRoot /var/www/xxxxxx.xx/html
      ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
      DirectoryIndex index.html 
    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was already banging my head against the wall. You are right, the reason is the file extension. I changed the .php to .html and it worked.